# How Create a image upload field with thumbnail with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I need a redux-form render field where I can upload image with a preview thumbnail and get base-64 value.

**Form**

```
<form className="AddProductForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.addProduct.bind(this))}>
    <div className="form-group clearfix">
        <img className="addProductImg pull-left" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview..." />
        <input className="pull-right addProductImgBtn" type="file" onChange={previewFile} />
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <Field name="name" component={this.renderField} type="text" placeholder="Product name" />
    </div>
    <Button onClick={close}>Cancel</Button>
    <button className='btn btn-primary addProductSave' type="submit" value="CONFIRM">Save</button>
</form>
```

**File upload**

```
function previewFile() {
    var preview = document.querySelector('.addProductImg');
    var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        preview.src = reader.result;
        let upImage = preview.src; 
        this.imageUrl = preview.src; // Base-64 value
    }
    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
        preview.src = "";
    }
}
```

I can get the base-64 value here, but I am unable to add this value into the existing field set.

**Submit function**

```
addProduct = (values) => {
    console.log("Field values", values);
    console.log("image base64 value", this.imageUrl);
}
```

Here inside `addProduct` function I want to get the image value with base64 encoding.

Comment: Please let us know what is the o/p of your console.log!